# What is the notebook of marks (school/uni) called in English?

Tags: word-request

In some school and universities in the world there are a small notebook in which the marks of the exams are written by the teachers. What is this notebook called in English?

Comment: ***Gradebook***?

Comment: I don't know because I am not native English speaker. But according to my search on Google it seems to be the name.

Comment: I am a native speaker, but it has been many years since I worried about, or even thought about, grades. I had a hard time even picturing / remembering the record you were  about. Hence the question mark.

Comment: "Gradebook" is what my wife calls it -- she teaches Freshman Composition at a university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **grade book**

According to the [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grade-book) is "a book in which a student's grades are recorded"

The same things on [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grade-book):
"A book in which marks for a student’s work are recorded"

Comment: British English: "Markbook". Sometimes, since teachers might use the same book to mark attendance as grades, it is the "register".